# How to install kali linux on android

Tags: linux

I want to install Kali Linux or similar (I.e. backbox backtrack) on my android. I'm using a one plus one and I wana be able to penttest on the fly.
Any suggestions or info like what r the fallbacks from having this OS running on my device if there r any. Any advice like that would be really appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally in order to do this, a perquisite is to root the device. There are actually dedicated apps on the play-store (Kali-Linux) (Backtrack is out of date)... that are an all in one process. Try a search and the application will guide you through the process. Be careful, you can end up bricking the device. I would recommend using an old one or ensuring backup data is on standby to reinstall via usb.